# Ribbon - Triplicate macros being created for no reason

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, macros, ribbon

I've added some macros to a custom group in the ribbon.  It is all fine, and works as expected.  However, I've noticed if I go back in to customize that group, I end up with triplicated macros and I'm not sure why.

1. Add the custom group, and the four macros
   [image]
2. Check that it works correctly in Ribbon (it does)
   [image]

BUT!

3. If I go back to the group, to add (or remove) a macro, suddenly the macros were all triplicated for some reason.

[image]

I did *nothing else* except add the macros to the group, click "Ok", then go back to customize the group.  Any ideas what might be causing this to occur?

Edit: MS Office 365, Excel Version 1806 (Build 10228.20104 Click-to-Run), Windows 7 Pro.

Comment: What is the version of Excel (2016, 2013, etc)? If it is 2016, what is the version and build number (found on File>Account>About)?

Comment: @RichMichaels - D'oh, of course! Edited in to OP at the end.

Comment: I can reproduce the same weird behavior. Interestingly, no additional entries are made on the ribbon, only the original three remain. You can also delete the extras but they do a Terminator on you and Come Back. The good news is the original three also continue to work. I'll see if I can get someone at MS to look into this.

Comment: I have reported this to Microsoft as a bug. If I learn of a resolution I report back, or maybe someone from MS will reply directly.

Comment: @RichMichaels wow, thanks! I was wondering if it was just me or not. For what it's worth I don't recall it doing this on previous versions.